# custom icomparer error - The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, icomparer

I'm trying to use IComparer with a generic type.

The code below generates the following error: "The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

If I remove the custom comparer from the OrderBy call then the code compiles and orders fine, however I need to be able to pass in my icomparer.
Also worth noting is that the code below works if i use type of object/string etc. but fails when I try and use generic type

```
public IQueryable<T> OrderResults<T, TU>(IQueryable<T> queryData, IComparer<TU> customComparer, string sortColumnName)
{
    var sortPropertyInfo = queryData.First().GetType().GetProperty(sortColumnName);
    return queryData.OrderBy(x => sortPropertyInfo.GetValue(x, null), customComparer);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet has some ambiguity caused by the fact that `GetValue(x,null)` returns type `System.Object`. Try the following:

```
public IQueryable<T> OrderResults<T, TU>(IQueryable<T> queryData, IComparer<TU> customComparer, string sortColumnName)
{
    var sortPropertyInfo = queryData.First().GetType().GetProperty(sortColumnName);
    return queryData.OrderBy(x => (TU)sortPropertyInfo.GetValue(x, null), customComparer);
}
```

This at least doesn't have a compile time error. If you have some code you're using for testing, I can verify that it works....